# html Formatting in python

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

i am using flask mail to and i am getting plain text rather than html formatting

Check below my code :

in app.py:

```
@app.route("/")

def index():

   msg = Message(subject='Report',sender="cg14@farazrabbani.xyz", recipients=['rakipandaga123456@gmail.com'])
   msg.body="hello"
   msg.html=render_template('report.html')
   mail.send(msg)
return "Sent"
```

in report.html:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css', _external=True) }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css', _external=True) }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Class name
                                    Type

```
                <div class="table100-body js-pscroll">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr class="row100 body">
                                <td class="cell100 column1">Cardio Blast</td>
                                <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
                                
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="row100 body">
                                <td class="cell100 column1">Pilates Reformer</td>
                                <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
                                
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="row100 body">
                                <td class="cell100 column1">Supple Spine and Shoulders</td>
                                <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
                                
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="row100 body">
                                <td class="cell100 column1">Yoga for Divas</td>
                                <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    

        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/popper.js', _external=True) }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js', _external=True) }}"></script>
```

I am getting only plain text i am not getting any html formatting in my mail.I tried a lot of ways like adding     external=true but still did'nt work at all

Comment: You can't include JS in a HTML email for one. Html emails support a very limited and archaic set of tags and attributes that because your HTML does not conform to I imagine is getting ignored

Comment: ok  i removed js then also not working atleast i should reflect the css but nothing works

Comment: You won't be able to use classes, you'll need to use inline styles. There are a lot of restrictions that you'll need to look up (e.g. https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/)